# Caching not working in MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I am struggling in implementing caching in my MVC application.
Below is the code I have added in my root directory web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
      <caching> 
<profiles>

          <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:20:00" location="Client" />

          <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:20:00" location="Client" />

          <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:20:00" location="Client" />

          <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:20:00" location="Client" />

          <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:02:00" location="Client" />

        </profiles>

      </caching>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" httpExpires="Sat, 11 June 2016 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlCustom="public" />
        <remove fileExtension=".js" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />

      </staticContent>

      <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" />

      <httpCompression dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage="80" />
      <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true">
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="ETag" value="0" />
            </customHeaders>

        </httpProtocol>

    </system.webServer>
```

Questions::
1)When I am checking the output via chrome developer tools network sections it is always taking images from server and not cache.I always get Status 200 response.I am using around 12 images in a sprite and they will never change.
2) I am not able to figure out how js and css bundles are cached.Every round trip again loads the complete bundle from server.Sometimes I get 304 response but I am not able to understand this fluctuating behaviour.

I am not able to drill down the issue.I have searched everywhere including this site but not able to put the optimum config settings to achieve the output.
Kindly someone help

Comment: Is this during development or using IIS Express? From what I recall, IIS Exp returning everything all the time.

Comment: Yes. IIS Express intentionally disables caching, since  caching static resources during development would make development very difficult.

Comment: No I am using express version of IIS.